# ArcGIS Online Web Map filters applied not reflected in Web App

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I'd like to apply filters to an existing table in a Web Map that is used by a Web App. However when applying filters in the Web Map, those filters applied are not reflected in the Web App. Is there a step that I'm missing for them to be reflected in the Web App? I was unable to find any ESRI documentation detailing this functionality.

Comment: "However when applying filters in the Web App, those filters applied are not reflected in the Web App."  - are you saying you are setting a Filter/Definition Query in the Web Map but your Web App (is this web app builder?) is not showing the filtered layer but rather all features from the layer?

Comment: Yes, my apologies for the typo. I've corrected it.

Comment: possibly caused by a widget that you have in your Web App, which is over-writing your filters. Check what widgets you have configured.

Comment: I have a user-configurable filter widget in the app but no pre-applied filter defaults. Would just having a widget affect anything? I should also note that I am using a View layer for the map but can't imagine that would make a difference.